# Overriding page.tpl.php for a menu_hook page

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I am trying to override template for a custom page I have in `hook_menu`.

```
 $items['announce_your_new_products'] = array(
    'title' => 'Announce Your New Products',
    'description' => 'Announce New Products.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('announce_new_product_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'file' => 'view_new_products.pages.inc',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,   );
```

I have read to override a specific node's page template is `page--node-[nid].tpl.php` and `page--announce_your_new_products.tpl.php`, with and without underscores, but since this doesn't have a nid I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how to achieve this.  I have tried `page--node-announce_your_new_prodcts.tpl.php` but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't need `node-` at the beginning of your template file name as your path isn't a node page. Going off the [Drupal 7 Theme Hook Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656), the file should be called:

```
page--announce_your_new_products.tpl.php
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
page--announce-your-new-products.tpl.php
```

Unfortunately the docs aren't very clear on which way will work.

Comment: underscores worked fine! i just needed to clear cache, should be part of the routine by now! ty